# Creative way for converting __attribute__ ((packed)) with visual cpp pragma

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, gcc, embedded

I'm working on a project which requires converting a massive codebase from c running on embedded target to a visual c++ software, all of the structures in the c code are defined with `__attribute__ ((pack))` which visual c++ does not support,
I cannot alter the c code.

I am looking for a workaround which will enable me to make vc++ refer to `__attribute__ ((packed))` the same way as it refers pragma pack,pop macros

the simple method of a define substituting the two is not possible because the `__attribute__ ((packed))` macro has a space between its words and the second word starts with a '('

is there any other creative way that won't make me alter the code?

Comment: There is not easy way as they did not think about it earlier to make it multi-compiler friendly

Comment: Re “converting a massive codebase from c … to a visual c++ software … I cannot alter the c code”: You cannot both convert the code and not alter the code. Pick one. Edit the question to clarify the task.

Comment: Do you mean your current "C" base needs to be compiled with a C++ compiler?Tell your boss "C" and "C++" are NOT the same language, at best C++ has "C" backward compatibility, but converting "C" to "C++" makes no sense. Is there even a business case, an analysis where the company checks if there will be a net gain in doing this?

Comment: I cannot alter some main parts of the code, this code is going to be wrapped in cpp code that works with the software, the only changes i am allowed to make are disconnecting hw drivers dependency

Comment: Are you bound to Visual C++? For example, MinGW provides the GNU compilers which were presumably used for the embedded target, too. AFAIK Clang supports this also.

Comment: Did you consider to use some "filter" script or program to pipe the source through to the Visual C++ compiler? You can write that in any language you see fit, automating the replacement. The intermediate sources do not need to be stored on disk. (At least I hope that CL is capable of reading sources from stdin. If it cannot, it confirms my dislike of it.)

Comment: If you are allowed to "disconnect" dependencies, you can as well clean up the code and replace it with appropriate `#pragma pack` directives. GCC and Clang understand them. You cannot introduce a macro, because the preprocessor cannot provide preprocessor directives as replacement text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would ask yourself whether in the VC compiled  version of the code the structures need to be packed?  Is there a functional reason for this, or just the whim of the original coder?

Secondly does the code use any other `__attribute__` directives?  If not then you can safely "remove" all the gcc `__attribute__` directives by defining an empty macro, either:

```
#define __attribute__(...)
```

in a "forced-include" header file (command line option `/FI <filename>`), or simply:

```
/D __attribute__(...)
```

on the command line.  The forced-include may be simpler if you need to add other directives to adapt the code.

So if the only use of `__attribute__` is for packing, and you don't really need packed structures, then you are done.  If however the packing is essential, and as you say:

> *all* of the structures in the c code are [packed]

Then you can globally apply packing via the command line using `/Zp` for the project, or in the forced-include file add:

```
#pragma pack(1)
```

If the solution is not truly suitable - for example not all the structures should be packed or `__attribute__` is used (and needed) for other purposes - then the path of least resistance may be to use gcc rather then VC for your Windows build.  The easiest way to do that is to use MinGW (minimal GNU for Windows).

Comment: what if the attribute has spaces? __attribute__ (...)

Comment: @DanielBelaish  It is not clear what you are asking.   The macro _definition_ cannot have whitespace between the symbol and the opening parenthesis of the parameter list.because anything after the whitespace is the _definition_, not the parameter list. In usage however, anything can appear between the parentheses and any amount of whitespace, including newlines may appear between the symbol `__attribute__` and the opening parenthesis.

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear, let's say I want to use the empty define as you proposed
however every `__attribute__ ((packed))` is two words in my code and therefore cannot be substituted with a single define macro, any proposition on how to overcome that?

Comment: @DanielBelaish. You could just try it and see that you are incorrect.  The macro is a parameterised macro (_function-like_ macro) with a variable length argument list, it _expects_ a parenthesised parameter list which syntactically `((packed))` satisfies.  Note that the `...` is not me eliding the code, that is _literal_, and indicates variable number of arguments.  You could write `__attribute__ (( my name is Dan), q+w))` or any such nonsense and it will be ignored.  That was my point about other `__attribute__` directives; it will remove them all, not just `pack`.